# Is it possible to route a subdomain to specific template group?

Tags: templating, routing, subdomain

We are looking for a way to route a subdomain to a specific template to use as a landing page.

Is there a way to do this without routing through index.html and redirecting to the specified template folder and file?

I can confirm that using the redirect **does** lose some of the user information, tracking codes etc. However it does retain the referral url from the 3rd party site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this example we have two domains:

```
http://www.example.com
http://subdomain.example.com
```

To use different templates for the subdomain, we can accomplished this with these steps:

1) Setup subdomain to point to a different directory on your server:

```
Domain: /home/wherever/public_html
Sub-domain: /home/wherever/public_html_subdomain
```

2) Copy your index.php file over to your new subdomain directory and update the `CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH` variable to point to the location you want to have your templates.  In this example, both template folders are above web root.

```
// index.php for domain
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../templates").'/');

// index.php for subdomain
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../templates_subdomain").'/');
```

Your template folders now look like:

```
/home/wherever/public_html
/home/wherever/public_html_subdomain
/home/wherever/templates
/home/wherever/templates_subdomain
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a way to do this without using a redirect, but if it's handled server-side via twig, it would be transparent and virtually instantaneous:

```
{% if siteUrl == "http://subdomain.site.com/"  %}
    {% redirect 'subdomainFolder' %}
{% endif %}
```

You could also redefine the default 'index' template using `indexTemplateFilenames` in your config file's multi-environment return array for that subdomain, but that would affect all index files for that subdomain in every uri and be pretty extreme:

```
/**
 * The template filenames Craft will look for within a directory to represent the directory’s “index” template when
 * matching a template path to a file on the front end.
 */
'indexTemplateFilenames' => array('index'),
```

As far as I know, I don't believe you can specify a full url in custom routes, only uri patterns — but perhaps someone else with more experience with this can add-in. And there may be some other options as well, that I don't know about.

Comment: Thanks Douglas - This is totally valid but I'd like to do it without a redirect if possible to retain tracking information , origin source etc. I'm not sure how much of this would remain if we redirect from the homepage. Functionally this works perfectly, we just have an odd use case.

Comment: Understood... but my understanding is that all requests are getting routed through craft anyway via a similar method (i.e. every request that craft manages is essentially a 404 redirect). I'm not sure there is much of a difference, whether it's initiated by twig in a template or via a craft service method — it's all a server side redirect. This shouldn't affect tracking information or origin source at all. I'm curious to see if anyone know any other options though.