# Admin - Manage entries based on a field type choice

Tags: entries, plugins

I have a potential upcoming project which will be the home for a businesses sporting events, they will have multiple event mini sites, about 4 each year. Each event mini-site will have the same structure but they will have different aesthetics.

The content areas will be:

- Home (Single)
- News (Channel)
- Videos (Channel)
- Photos (Channel)
- Results (Single)
- Media Contacts (Single)

I have no problem setting up the site but I would like offer the client the ability to access an edit entries screen that has just the content for that event.

I.e they could choose the Event from an drop down and they would only see the Singles, Channels and Structures related to that event.

Also adding the ability to restrict some users access to a particular events content

Is this possible? Has anyone built a plugin for something like this? or know how to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It's not (yet) possible to have multiple websites with dedicated front-end and back-end views within one Craft installation (Multi-site feature). There's some users that mis-use Craft's localization feature for this, but I definitely wouldn't recommend this.

But it is actually not a problem at all to route all your subdomains to individual template folders of a single installation (→ [Is it possible to route a subdomain to specific template group?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/4717/125)). And for the backend, I'd simply create a user group for each of your events and configure the permissions accordingly (→ [Assign permissions to users and groups](https://buildwithcraft.com/features/users)). So user group "Summer Party" has only access to sections belonging to that sub-site. Individual users can be assigned to more than one group if necessary.

Instead of having lots of single sections ("Summer Party - Home", "Summer Party - Results", "Summer Party - Media Contacts") I would recommend to look into replacing this with a single structure section ("Summer Party - Pages") with multiple entry types. And for your media channels you could also consider not using entries at all and assign fields to your assets directly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Craft doesn't offer any kind of multi-site support (like MSM in ExpressionEngine, or Wordpress Network/MU) – see [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/408/are-there-any-intentions-to-release-multisite-support-for-craft) for more information.

If your Events really are complex enough to warrant a multi-site solution, I guess this is one of those (very few!) cases where Craft might not be your best option right now.

If you still want to use Craft, I can think of a few possible solutions off the top of my head:

1. Have one Craft install per Event/mini-site. Use symlinking to share
   things like core and config fils, plugins and templates.
2. Create one Structure per event, containing your "Singles". Create [Entry Types](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries#entry-types) in that Structure for "Home", "Results" and "Media Contacts". Have News, Videos and Photos be regular/global Channels, but add a required Relationship field where the relevant Event Structure is set.
3. Same as above, except you create one Structure (three levels deep) that holds all Events.
4. Create top level categories representing your Events, and build on that.
5. Go all in and create all your neccessary Channels and Singles per Event. Pre- or postfix all sources with the event name, e.g. "News – Superbowl 2015", "Videos – Superbowl 2015" and restrict access as neccessary.
6. Create a custom locale per event, and piggyback on Craft's excellent [multilocale](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/localization-guide) functionality.