# Two domains, one server with Craft installed

Tags: url, server

I already have Craft running on a single domain name successfully.

For my client, we've bought a second domain name for a mini site for SEO purposes, some of which we'd like to use Craft on.

What are my options?

I'd like to try to use the same Craft login to manage both sites for the client. The site uses almost identical resources, it would just need a different index page and unique named pages.

Or do I have to go down the vhosts route?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at this question: [Site set up with mutiple sub domains](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/9763/125).