# Getting Page Not Found error for my custom subdomain setup

Tags: routing, subdomain

I want to setup a new custom subdomain (va.domain.com) within the project of my existing domain (craft.domain.com) using `homestead`.

So I referred to this [this answer on craftexchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4717/is-it-possible-to-route-a-subdomain-to-specific-template-group) and followed all the steps.

I now have a separate folder at the root level called `public_va`. Inside that I have my `index.php`with this define statement that is supposed to change the path:

```
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../templates_va").'/');
```

Inside of the `craft`folder I have created a folder called `templates_va` that is a sibling of the existing `templates` folder. And I put in a simple index.html file in just for testing.

Now when I point my browser to `va.domain.com`, it just shows me:

```
Page Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I also tried creating a new (single) section called `va_homepage` in the CP backend but I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this? My error logs inside my vagrant box show nothing. The domain itself has been setup correctly via homestead. I verified by routing request to a static file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed. The dynamic path to the new templates folder was wrong:

```
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../templates_va").'/');
```